# Block all items, except the first element in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to create a ListView with particular elements. But when the listview shows for the 1st time, 1 only enabled the first element and the rest blocked. I tried to block the list and later listView.getChildAt(0).setEnabled(true). But Nothing happens.

Comment: by block, i'm assuming you mean un-clickable???

Comment: Yes, I want to the 1st item on the listView are clickable, and the rest Unclickable.

Comment: Are you using a custom ListView?

Comment: Yeah, I use a listView, with my custom Adapter, and I need to make the 1st item on listView clickable and the rest, unclickable

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use an id property of the object on the adapter. I assume that you hold your data on an array. When you inflate the view, if the index on the array is 0, then set the property setEnabled to true, or else setEnabled to false.